# Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x99' for column "'comment_body_value'"

Tags: 7, comments

How can I fix the following error I get from a Drupal 7 site?

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x99' for column "'comment_body_value'

I read it is about users posting emojis that cannot be handled by Drupal/MySQL.

I don't care if the comments are being stripped off the emojis, or converted as long as it does not trigger an error to the end-user. The simpler the solution the better.
I found a few modules, for example the [Emoji Scrub](https://www.drupal.org/project/emoji_scrub) module that isn't covered by the security advisory policy.

Comment: This explains how to solve this issue: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/solving-emoji-problem-drupal-7

Comment: Thank you Jaypan, I'm happy to see you here. By the way for one reason or another I cannot assign your comment as the answer.

Comment: I just posted it as an answer below. You can mark that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explains how to solve this issue: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/solving-emoji-problem-drupal-7